# Why page.render takes image only from top of the page in PhantomsJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I use PhantomJS to get some data from Facebook Groups.

I have pretty simple flow:

1. open page
2. print screen
3. scroll down
4. go to step 2

From logs I see that web page height increases but images I get - the same all the time.

Here is relevant code:

```
var index_screen  = 0;

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
     if (msg == "__screen__") {
    console.log("print screen");
   page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 1680, height: 1050 };
    page.render(index_screen + "_test.png");
    index_screen++;   
    }


...


 evaluate(page, function() {  

var scrollInterval = setInterval(function() {   

                    console.log("__screen__");

                    console.log("screen hight: ",  document.body.scrollHeight); 

                    window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;    

                    console.log("after screen: ",  window.document.body.scrollTop);


                    }, 15000);

 }); // end evaluate
```

The output I get:

```
page: screen hight:  4494
page: after screen:  4194

page: screen hight:  8397
page: after screen:  8097

page: screen hight:  12390
page: after screen:  12090

...
```

It means that code works and I scroll down, but all images show me top of the page.

Did I miss something?

Please help,

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 1680, height: 1050 };` line is saying "*always give me the top 1050 pixels of the page*".

If 'h' is the current screen height, and `var prevHeight = 0` initially, you want to do this:

```
page.clipRect = { top: prevHeight, left: 0, width: 1680, height: h - prevHeight };
prevHeight = h;
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something simple